# How to debug why cURL not show response on command line?

Tags: macos, http, nginx, curl, terminal

I'm not sure if this cause by the settings in my

- Web server
- Network firewall
- or something wrong with my cURL command.

When I run the curl command

```
curl -s www.bunlongheng.com/run/banner
```

I see nothing on my command line on Terminal on my MacBook Pro.

---

## BUT

If I paste this [URL](https://www.bunlongheng.com/run/banner) on Chrome, I see this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we run

```
curl -I www.bunlongheng.com/run/banner
```

You see `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`, so you need

```
curl -L -s www.bunlongheng.com/run/banner

       -L, --location
              (HTTP) If the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different loca-
              tion (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX response code), this option  will
              make curl redo the request on the new place. If used together with -i, --include or
              -I, --head, headers from all requested pages will be shown. When authentication  is
              used, curl only sends its credentials to the initial host. If a redirect takes curl
              to a different host, it won't be able to  intercept  the  user+password.  See  also
              --location-trusted  on how to change this. You can limit the amount of redirects to
              follow by using the --max-redirs option.

              When curl follows a redirect and the request is not a plain GET (for  example  POST
              or  PUT), it will do the following request with a GET if the HTTP response was 301,
              302, or 303. If the response code was any other 3xx code,  curl  will  re-send  the
              following request using the same unmodified method.

              You  can  tell curl to not change the non-GET request method to GET after a 30x re-
              sponse by using the dedicated options for that: --post301, --post302 and --post303.
```

Comment: How do I get rid of progress or download details? : https://i.imgur.com/oAOGIYy.png

Comment: `curl -sL www.bunlongheng.com/run/print | sed 's/-L/-sL/' | bash`